# Custom Tile layer with php call on Android

Tags: php, android, android-mapview, osmdroid

I need to implement a layer of non-static custom tiles in my Android App that uses OSMdroid for the MapView. The tiles are rendered when a php script is called, which works perfectly for the web, but I am not sure whether Android/OSMdroid MapView can also display the tiles that way?
The call looks like

```
http://my.url/get_tile.php?zoom=1&coords=2,3
```

which returns a 256x256px .png image at the zoom level 2 with the OSM x,y-coordiantes 2,3.

Is there a way to implement these tiles directly with the php call from the app into a MapView with e.g. XYTileSource? Or would I need a web-script that first renders the tiles into the corresponding pyramid from which XYTileSource?

Answer (score 1):

An XYTileSourse want do exactly what you want but it's very close.  I think you just need to do your own version and put your own getTileURLString method dealing with the slightly different formatting of the x,y,zoom parameters.  If you look at the source for the XYTileSourse you will see that it's only 20 lins and you only need to change 2 of them.

Comment: thanks Ifor! I changed line 17 to match the string format of my request - return getBaseUrl() + "zoom=" + aTile.getZoomLevel() + "&coords=" + aTile.getX() + "," + aTile.getY() + mImageFilenameEnding; I suppose the second line to be changed would be about actually fetching the php-response? Do I need HttpClient for that?! Or am I on the wrong way here?!

Comment: I really only meant that line.  So lang as the response is the tile in png format I think the rest of it should just work, I have never looked at the response handeling code.